# CSS3 box-shadow on hover combined with partial border-radius bug in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, box-shadow

Where is very strange bug when i use box-shadow on hover on element with partial border-radius.

[image]

Appears in Chrome 70.0.3534.4 on Win10
Here is the snippet:

```css
#test {
  width: 300px;
  height: 70px;  
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
#test:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px 0 #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

maybe somebody know workaround for this?

Comment: outline instead?

Comment: maybe, but i need shadow with blur

Comment: try adding vendor prefixes; #test:hover {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px 0 #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px 0 #000;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px 0 #000;
}

Comment: @yjs it's useless

Answer (score 0):

It might be how you are using the border-radius property...Have you tried this shortened version:

`border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;`

This above does the exact same thing that you currently have as: `border-top-left-radius: 5px;` and `border-top-right-radius: 5px;`

Explaining this shortened version:

border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;

the first `5px` in this statement is for `top left`, second `5px` is `top right`, first `0` is `bottom right` and last `0` is `bottom left`.

This is the preferred way to write `border-radius` as it only uses 1 line of code rather than having to have additional lines of code just for the border-radius - Do more, write less :)

I haven't tested this out on Chrome's version 70+ as my version is 68.xxx and I'm unable to update as it says the browser is already up-to-date...

Comment: but the question is about chrome 70